# Clickhouse: how long are kafka schema registry IPs cached for?

Tags: clickhouse, clickhouse-kafka

We are using [Clickhouse's Kafka Engine](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/integrations/kafka) with the `format_avro_schema_registry_url` SETTING as described [here](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/settings/formats#format_avro_schema_registry_url).

After some time we see the following errors show up in the logs (ip removed):

```
Code: 1000. DB::Exception: Timeout: connect timed out: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:443: while fetching schema id = 1566: while parsing Kafka message
```

It seems one of our three Clickhouse nodes has the IP of the kafka schema registry stored somewhere and is keeping it for too long. The IP changes, resulting in the error.

Restarting the Clickhouse service with:

```
systemctl restart clickhouse-server
```

makes the errors go away.

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can consider disabling the dns cache in your environment with this setting:
https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/server-configuration-parameters/settings#disable_internal_dns_cache

There also `SYSTEM DROP DNS CACHE` command for one of operations:
https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/system#drop-dns-cache

Finally, the dns cache update period is controlled by this setting:
https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/server-configuration-parameters/settings#dns_cache_update_period