# Clickhouse: n/n brokers are down

Tags: clickhouse, clickhouse-kafka

We have set up a few tables with `ENGINE = Kafka()` across our three node Clickhouse staging cluster.

In the logs we can frequently see this error:

`[rdk:ERROR] [thrd:GroupCoordinator]: 15/15 brokers are down`

I am sure the brokers are not down (not a single one). Also checking the topics, none of the currently 16 consumed topics have developed any lag.

Restarting the Clickhouse service with:

`systemctl restart clickhouse-server`

makes the errors go away (deleting and recreating the tables as well).

I was hoping [disabling the DNS cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76403250/clickhouse-how-long-are-kafka-schema-registry-ips-cached-for) would help, but it didn't. Is it possible these occur when there is not much data?

Or any other ideas I could try?

```
SELECT version()

┌─version()─┐
│ 23.1.3.5  │
└───────────┘
```

Comment: upgrade to 23.3
and check /var/log/clickhouse-server/clickhouse-server.log
usually it means your connection from clickhouse to kafka lost, check credentials and ensure clickhouse can connect to kafka

Answer (score 1):

```
kafka-status
```

- Kafka status. Make sure that all of the brokers are up and running
- check /`etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml` file.
  for following

`KAFKA_BROKERS` setting check

Increase the `KAFKA_RECONNECT_INTERVAL` setting. This setting controls how often `Clickhouse` will try to reconnect to a down `broker`.

Increase the `KAFKA_POLL_TIMEOUT` setting. This setting controls how long Clickhouse will wait for a response from Kafka before it considers the broker to be down.

If none of these work check `clickhouse` logs & post relevant events for further troubleshooting